# Оглавление, номера наезжают на текст

Tags: latex

При разработке документа, нумерация заголовков временами становится очень длинной. И в оглавлении номера начинают заходить на текст (как в картинке). В самом документе все хорошо, текст отстоит от номера на нормальном расстоянии... Подскажите, куда копать?[image: пример:]

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Если кому поможет - пакет `{titletoc}`.

Командами:

```
\dottedcontents{section}[]{}{}{}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[]{}{}{}
```

все настраивается